# when DataFrame has mutliIndex,how to visualize it?

Tags: visualization

I'm doing the "video games sales" project downloaded from kaggle, the data is like this:
[image: data.head()]

and I want to know on each Platform, which are the most three popular Genres? but I don't know how to visualize it, I use pandas to filter the data, here is the code:
[image: filter the data]

so how could I use pandas(or seaborn,etc.) to finish this target? I'm appreciate for your answers...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## How to keep the top 3

### In a convenient DataFrame

You can use the method `nlargest` to keep the best 3 of each index.

```
df.groupby(["Genre","Platform"]).size()
        .reset_index(level=1)
        .groupby("Platform")[0]
        .nlargest(3).to_frame("Game_count)
```

### Step by step explanation

- I assumed that, by "popularity", you meaan the game count. We first group by`Genre` and `Platform`, and we take the size of each group, as you did but with both the columns swapped.

  ```
  step1 = df.groupby(["Genre", "Platform"]).size()
  ```

[image: Step 1]

- We reset the index to drop one level, so we have indices set to Genre.

  ```
  step2 = step1.reset_index(level=1)
  ```

[image: Step 2]

- We group back to `Platform` and keep the 3 largest values

  ```
  step3 = step2.groupby("Platform")[0].nlargest(3) # 0 is the default name of the size column.
  ```

[image: Step 3]

- We make it a DataFrame, assigning an appropriate name.

  ```
  top3_df = step3.toframe("Game_count")
  ```

### Result

[image: Resulting dataframe]

---

## How to visualize

Since we have many platforms and many genres (even considering the Top3 only), we cannot reasonably represent all the informations in a single plot. But we can have multiple plots.

- Let's first reset the index, to flatten our dataframe. We will also list our genres in an alphabetic order.

  ```
  import seaborn as sns
  top3_df.reset_index(inplace=True)
  genres = top3_df.Genre.sort_values().unique()
  ```
- We have to assign each genre to a specific color, so each keeps its color in all plots. We will use a seaborn color_palette and link it to each genre thanks to a dictionary.

  ```
  genres_palette = dict(zip(genres, sns.color_palette("Set3", len(genre))
  ```
- Now, let's design a function to plot each platform in a separate axe. We also pass it our palette dictionary :

  ```
  def plot_platform(dataframe, name, ax):
      # We also sort the dataframe in decreasing order of Game count
      sns.barplot(x="Genre", y="Game_count", 
              data=dataframe.sort_values("Game_count", ascending=False),
              palette=genre_palette, ax=ax)
      ax.set_title(f"By platform: {name}")
  ```
- Finally plotting...

  ```
  fig = plt.figure(figsize=(20,32), constrained_layout=True) # Quite big to fit all data comfortably
  gridspecs = fig.add_gridspecs((len(platforms)+3) // 3, 4) # A grid of width 4

  # One call to our custom plot function by platform:
  for index, platform in enumerate(platforms):
     # Next cell in our grid. We let the right-most column for the legend
     ax = fig.add_subplot(gridspecs[index // 3, index % 3])
     plot_platform(top3_df[top3_df.Platform==platform], platform, ax)

  # Now adding the legends
  from matplotlib.patches import Patch
  # The entire fourth column is for the legend
  fig_legend_ax = fig.add_subplot(gridspecs[0:,-1])
  fig_legend_ax.axis("off")
  fig_legend_ax.legend(
          # One patch per genre, with its color and name.
          handles=[Patch(facevolor=col, label=genre) for genre, col in genre_palette.items()], 
          # Let's make it quite big and with no visible frame
          loc="center left", frameon=False, prop={"size": 25})

   plt.show()
  ```

### Result

Please note that the following preview is largely zoomed-out.

[image: Global visualization]

Of course, you can customize it with other color palette, sizes and layouts.

Answer (score 0):

So your question is how to plot the top 3 game genres for each game platform (console). You are definitely on the right track in using the `groupby` method.

It is a bit long winded, but this would definitely do the job:

```
c = df.groupby(["Platform", "Genre"]).size().reset_index()
c.columns = ["Platform", "Genre", "Frequency"]

for p in df["Platform"].unique():
    """
    This line will take a subset of the c dataframe such that it only contains
    entries for a particular platform.
    The .sort_values() method will then arrange the frequency in descending order.
    The .head(n) will then take the top n entries and therefore, the top three genres
    for a particular platform.
    """
    df_ = c[c["Platform"] == p].sort_values("Frequency")
    sns.barplot(x = "Platform", y = "Frequency", hue = "Genre", data = df_)
    plt.show()
```

Here, you can edit the code so that for each platform, each graph appears on a separate axis.